# Implement and query MYSQL foreign key which refers to two tables

Tags: mysql

I have two tables **Hotels** and **Activities**

```
Hotels
id    |   name      |
1     | hilton      |
2     | taj samudra |
3     | galadari    |


Activities
    id   |   name          |
    1    |  air balloon    |
    2    |  whale watching |
    3    |  jungle safari  |
```

also I have a another table **Tour**

```
id      | starting_location_id | starting_location_type 
1       | 1                    | hotel
2       | 1                    | activity
```

user can start the Tour from hotel or activity.

What I want is to pass the `id` and need to get the data like this using a join

```
id   | name
1    | hitlon
2    | air baloon
```

If I future explain, I want a foreign key which can refer to multiple tables.
Note :- This is not implemented yet. I want to implement this kind of scenario. I want to pass the `id` in the **Tour** table and need to get the associated data for that record.

Is this possible to in MYSQL?

Comment: Unclear what you are asking - Can you explain it more clearly how you got that output, what id did you pass, which table you joined etc?

Comment: @SMA I've update my question

Comment: ' I want a foreign key which can refer to multiple tables' - No that's not possible.But I don't think you need  one to do what you want,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below -

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=05ce239d08bd0f9f8e6e733ef0eff072)**

```
select t1.id,coalesce(h.name,a.name) as name 
from tour t1 
left join hotels h on t1.starting_location_id=h.id and starting_location_type='hotel'
left join Activities a on t1.starting_location_id=a.id and starting_location_type='activity'

OUTPUT:

id  name
2   air balloon
1   hilton
```

Comment: How do I make a FK starting_location_id that refers to tables.

Comment: where you want to refer in table @PathumSamararathna

Comment: Now I see your Fiddle. I thought a foreign key is a must to a join query. =) Thanks a lot.